# Accessing Play! Framework server using different IP's on same box

Tags: networking, playframework

I would like to Access Play! Framework application over the LAN using different IP's on same box.

example:

Play is running on 192.168.1.12:9000 on Server with 2 NIC cards. The IP address of the second NIC card is 192.168.2.40. I'm able to access 192.168.1.12:9000, But i'm not able to access 192.168.2.40:9000 over the LAN. Ports are open in the firewall. is there any setting which needs to be tweaked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some case, port under a certain defined number can be blocked. try setting another port, higher than 9000.

Even better would be a frontserver (apache/lighthttp/nginx) redirecting traffic to the right server behind based upon domain names.

Comment: I used port 9003. Still i'm unable to connect.

Comment: I used port 29000. It connected in my sys3 and sys5 after some time after that (some 5 minutes) itried to refresh the page it showed error page: could not connect. I used commands nc, telnet to ping to port. It printed: cannot find route to host. I don't know why it connected and why it disappeared.